# Importing Data into SharePoint 2010 from SQL Server

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm creating a PowerShell script to migrate data from a SQL Server database into SharePoint 2010 lists.  I have to read 500,000+ records from the database, perform some operations on it and then import it into various SharePoint lists.  I can get this to work but essentially I'm looking for the fastest way to import this amount of data into SharePoint.

I have tried using the SharePoint API to add and update list items directly but I left this to run over night and it wasn't finished in the morning.

I have also tried using the lists.asmx web service to upload pre-generated XML for each item however this approach doesn't seem especially fast either.  The XML for this is broken down into batches to avoid timing out the web service request.  I tried uploading the batches using asynchronous web service requests but that basically killed the SharePoint site so now I'm just using synchronous requests which is also slow.

Any suggestions for how to read from SQL Server, transform the data and add it to SharePoint lists?

**Addition**

When the items from the database are manipulated to be inserted into the SharePoint lists, this results in 771,900 individual list items to be inserted.

Comment: Did you check how many records get processed per minute? SharePoint has no built-in bulk load features, its database structure is terrible performance-wise and you have already approached the problem from many different angles, so I think it will take you a lot of time to achieve any significant gains. If you know the current speed of the process, you can estimate how much time it will take and decide if it's worth to optimize it.

Comment: Unfortunately a lot of time isn't something I have for this.  Based on the average time taken so far the items per minute inserted into sharepoint is 432.  I've extrapolated this out to calculate a total running time of 29-30 hours (!!!!!!).

Comment: The source database and SP are on different machines but at this point I am no longer interacting with the source - just uploading XML that has been already generated from it from my local machine (all the XML files are < 200kb).  The SharePoint machine is currently usage 90%+ of the CPU and around 80% of RAM.

Comment: Do you need to import the data, or just have the data displayed as lists in sharepoint?

Comment: Needs to be fully imported into SharePoint.

Comment: w3wp.exe and sqlserver.exe are the culprits.  Figured out a way to improve the speed though - turn off workflows on the lists!  Reduced the time for importing a batch by roughly a factor of 10!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling workflows on lists can greatly improve performance.  New estimated time for import is down to just over 7 hours from the original estimated 29 hours.

Comment: Were this workflows configured to start when a new item was created **or** is it enough to only associate a workflow with a list to create performance problems?

Comment: They were configured to start when a new item was created.  So every XML file that was uploaded created 150 items causing the workflows to run for each of them.  During normal operation the workflows don't cause any noticeable performance problems.

Comment: Just a note; when the process was ran again against the server it took a little over 3 hours.  My estimation of 7 hours was a bit out so I think we can assume that the 29 hours estimation would have been over the actual time as well.